# How to find the cost here?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> $A,B$ and $C$ are three commodities. A packet containing $5$ pieces of $A$,$3$ of $B$ and $7$ of $C$ costs $\$24.50$ . A packet containing $2,1$ and $3$ of $A, B$ and $C$ respectively costs $\$17.00$ The cost of a packet containing $16, 9$ and $23$ items of $A,B$ and $C$ respectively is......" and answer is $\$100$

But i can't understand how the answer is derived. it is 3 variables in 2 equations! so isn't the info lacking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x$ = cost of a piece of A

$y$ = cost of a piece of B

$z $= cost of a piece of C.

$5x + 3y + 7z = 24.5$

$2x + y + 3z = 17$

$16x + 9y + 23z = 2(5x + 3y + 7z) + 3(2x + y + 3z) = 2*24.5 + 3*17 = 100$

Answer (score 1):

Note that the last combination is exactly twice the first one and three times the second package. This means you don't have to solve the exact value of the variables.